# What would be a good Java library for implementing a graphical programming interface?

Tags: java, programming, graphs

I would like to make a graphical programming interface somewhat like Blender's node interface, which looks like this:

[image: Blender node interface screenshot]

There's no need for automatic layout of the graph, the user's going to manually drag and drop all the nodes around manually.

What does matter:

- It looks good
- It allows for the connection points to be different colours
- It allows for curved connection lines (bicubic or whatever)
- Ideally, it integrates well with Swing, because that's what the application is currently using.

Prefuse I'm pretty sure could be adapted to do this sort of rendering - I'm not entirely sure whether it can do the connections to specific points, but maybe it can... I would be willing to give it a shot if it were the last graph drawing library on the planet.

But Prefuse is old and unmaintained, and there must be a dozen new libraries out there, so what's good?